# how to send parameter to a PHP to sort a DB

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

how can I connect a HTML page that send parameter to a PHP page that should sort a DB through those parameters?

Basically I have a HTML form page with a drop down menu that send the name of a DB column.
On the PHP I have tha code that access the DB but I can't figure out how to get those name and sort the DB through that name (or variable or flag).

I tried with a

```
  $name = $_POST['nameOfTheHtmlFormField'];
```

But the value of $name is NULL if I echo it.

Plus, I have no idea how to communicate that flag to a sort command in the PHP

Do you have any clue or resource I can look up?

Thank you.

Comment: if `$name` is NULL< then you are not making valid posts

Comment: please submit your form code here. You may have forgotten a method="post" on the <form> tag?

Comment: please edit your question

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to be using $_POST? From what I understood from your post, you want to really be using the $_GET variable.

**$_POST** is for sending data to a script, for example a web form

**$_GET** is used to fetch the value of a parameter within a url, for example;

```
URL: /exampleScript.php?type=GetData&field=Username

echo $_GET['type']; // Outputs GetData
echo $_GET['field'] // Outputs Username
```

It seems like this is the issue with your script as I can't see why you want use a form as a link.